# Json array details show in angularjs with ionic

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I have category array. there are more category. I need show categories in home page as a list. I attached some screen shot below this question. What is the wrong in this code.

**catlist.js**

```
app.factory('category', ['$http', function($http) { 

return $http.get('http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php')


       .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova','ngRoute'])
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

category.success(function(data) {
   $scope.userslists = data;
  });


$scope.minusOne = function(index) {
$scope.products[index].dislikes += 1;


};
    }])
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-view>

<div class="bar bar-header bar-dark" style="margin-top: initial;height: 55px;">
    <h1 class="title" style="margin-top: 10px;">FREE SHOPPING</h1>

    <div side="left" style="margin-top: 12px;">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">


    </button>
        </div>
  </div>


  <ion-content scroll="true" has-bouncing="false" class="has-header nk-colorGrey">

<div class="bodyback" ng-repeat="cat in category">    
<ion-item    class="item widget uib_w_109 d-margins item-button-right" data-uib="ionic/list_item_button" data-ver="0"> {{ cat.name }}  <br>
            <label style="display:none;">{{ cat.term_id }}</label>



     </ion-item>

  </div>

  </ion-content>

    <div class="upage-outer fixed-header-footer">
    <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left"></div>

</div>
```

**categorylist-product.json**

```
{
"category": [{
    "term_id": "10",
    "name": "Arden Grange",
    "slug": "arden-grange",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "47",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange, Premium",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 16:13:04",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "50",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Puppy\/Junior Large Breed",
        "post_date": "2015-10-21 04:56:23",
        "post_author": "5"
    }, {
        "ID": "53",
        "post_title": "Arden Grange Weaning\/Puppy",
        "post_date": "2015-10-22 12:52:35",
        "post_author": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "term_id": "8",
    "name": "Menu 1",
    "slug": "menu-1",
    "products": [{
        "ID": "38",
        "post_title": "Home",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:43:44",
        "post_author": "1"
    }, {
        "ID": "30",
        "post_title": "",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:13:56",
        "post_author": "1"
    }, {
        "ID": "31",
        "post_title": "",
        "post_date": "2015-10-20 10:13:57",
        "post_author": "1"
    }]
}]
}
```

[image]

Comment: inside your controller you forgot to insert your factory name

Comment: Also `success` and `error` methods are deprecated and you should don't use them.

Comment: Now I added factory name. but, not work

Comment: In your factory you should return only the request(promise), then in your controller in you can call **`THEN`** method.

Comment: Then What I need to use for 'success' and 'error'

Comment: `.then(function(data) {
                    if (data.forecast==='good') {
                        prepareFishingTrip();
                    } else {
                        prepareSundayRoastDinner();
                    }
                }, function(error) {
                    prepareSundayRoastDinner();
                });`

Like this, Is this ok.

Comment: After remove the `success` and `error` methods from factory, just change your controller to: `category.then(function(data) {
   $scope.userslists = data;
  });`

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Now I have, like this error [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: categoryProvider <- category <- HomeController